# Face recognition with cnn for single person

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, face-recognition

I am training CNN model to recognize the face in such way that the model would have only two class. One is "my face", another one is "not my face".
It means it will a binary classifier to recognize my face.

I have tried following approaches to make it work.

> Took my face as positive and few other faces as negative class. In
>   this approach, I am facing problems with the untrained faces. Some
>   faces which are not trained are recognizing as my face. This problem
>   is called "false positive".

I want to get rid of false positive case. Can anyone suggest me some tricks with the datasets or CNN network that I should use to make it work?

Apart from CNN if any other techniques are available. Please suggest me.

Comment: more data? how many other faces do you have?

Comment: For now just 10 different face. Then I am augmenting it using rotation in range of 5 degree and slightly changing position of face.

Comment: why not getting a bigger set of faces eg. from kaggle and train your network with more different faces?

Comment: Thanks @FlorianH! But I want to know if this is the only technique available. Can't I use some kind of technique that can generate negative image (I don't know such kind of technique, but just want to create this.) I want to know if any algorithm is available that can learn one class better than the other class.

Comment: Ok, got your point, but no answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False positives will plague you with this type of classification and your specific objective.

My experience tells me the best solution would be to **test a number of different** machine learning techniques/models on the same data set until you discover the one that gives the best results.

As Florian H suggested, you could also get a bigger dataset with more faces. Or maybe your face/the feature set is just similar to the other face.

Lastly, I suggest that you go look at a tool called **OpenCV** and consult their docs on machine learning.

What do mean by "Can't I use some kind of technique that can generate negative image (I don't know such kind of technique, but just want to create this.)". Are you perhaps referring to watershed or thresholding? OpenCV's documentation includes these topics.

Also, giving a more detailed explanation of your chosen features, how you extract, etc, ... makes it far easier for more experienced people to guide you with best practices and techniques so that you can improve your results.

Comment: It is best not to answer when the question is off topic or in too bad shape. [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572)

Comment: As Florian H suggested me to take more negative images, so for this, I am trying to make such a code that will generate negative images for my face. The generated images will be somewhat similar to my original face but not exactly as my face. I think this force the CNN to extract my face features very precisely.

Comment: @E_net4, I want to make a binary classifier for my face so I mentioned the title and I described the way and dataset in the description. I feel there is not problem. But if you find it off topic or it's not clear, you can downvote it and ask me to clear it. let me know if information I gave is not enough.

Comment: @Akhilesh You may wish to re-read [ask] and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).